# Preventing read while an update is underway MongoDB(or making sure I have the latest info)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am creating a Wallet Payment API in Node and Mongoose. How do I prevent reading erroneous wallet balances in situations such as:

- The wallet balance was updated while my code was reading the Wallet document. How do I make my code see the new Updated Balance and not the old one?
- The wallet was deleted while I was reading the document

How do I make sure I always have the correct and latest information?

Comment: Your question is a little broad. I'd suggest looking into [Read Concern](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/read-concern/) as a starting point, and then transactions afterwards if applicable

Comment: @user20042973 I understand. what i am asking is how I am going to handle a hypothetical scenario in which one of my documents in a collection got updated while I was reading it, and how do I get the updated value in that case